# System directory to java list

Tags: java, json, angular

I'm not very familiar with json and I'm trying to pass a computer directory to json to paint it on the web with PrimeNG (Angular) I'm trying to generate a structure like this https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/assets/showcase/data/filesystem.json but I do not get it Any ideas? Thank you

I'm only need help to save the full folder / files structure in objects / list
Best Regards

*The class "carpeta" have a String(name) and two list one for folders and other for files

This is my actual code:

```
 static carpeta raiz = new carpeta(new File(ruta).getName());

public static void recursiveSearch(File file ) {
     File[] filesList = file.listFiles();

     for (File f : filesList) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
            //  raiz.addCarpetas(Carpeta);
                carpeta actual = new carpeta(f.getName());
                raiz.addCarpetas(actual);

                System.out.println("Directoy name is  -------------->" + f.getName());
                System.out.println("BuscaDentro");
                recursiveSearch(f);
            }
            if( f.isFile() ){
                System.out.println("File name is  -------------->" + f.getName());
            }
            System.out.println("Siguiente");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following recursive method:

```
public MyFileDetails recursiveSearch(File file) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        return new MyFileDetails(file.getName());
    }
    List<MyFileDetails> children = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] filesList = file.listFiles();
    for (File f : filesList) {
        children.add(recursiveSearch(f));
    }
    return new MyFolderDetails(file.getName(), children);
}
```

With `MyFileDetails`:

```
public class MyFileDetails {
    private String name;

    public MyFileDetails(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And `MyFolderDetails`:

```
public class MyFolderDetails extends MyFileDetails {
    private List<MyFileDetails> children;

    public MyFolderDetails(String name, List<MyFileDetails> children) {
        super(name);
        this.children = children;
    }

    public List<MyFileDetails> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}
```

It will return an Object with all children, if you pass a folder.

```
MyFileDetails details = recursiveSearch(new File("/path/to/my-test-folder/"));
```

Of course you can add some more fields (e.g. file size, or an explicit  mark for folders) to the details objects, to get the output you showed.